# switch case not working matlab

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, case

I am writing a function in MATLAB to count a number of matrices based off of one of their column values.

For example

```
B=
1.0000    0  0.3000
0         0  0.3000
```

And so on. Column 3 will vary between matrices but will be the same throughout the matrix. This third column can have the values .2:.05:.8 and I have a case for each of these.

I am experiencing some really strange results. When run through the switch case many times the case for .3 never functions even though I can clearly see that the switch statement was assigned as .3. I have investigated this with greater precision turned on and the switch variable and the case are most certainly identical.

I have pasted a more complete section of the code below. the function *twolayer* returns [0/1  0/1 bitrate], with the bitrate being the switch variable. Please let me know if there is anything I am doing wrong when implementing the switch case. I have tried the same code using if elseif and ran into the same problem, I believe it is an issue of how MATLAB is comparing numbers. Thank you in advance!

```
for k=1:15
    A(k,1:3)=twolayer(j,X(1,i));
end  
%Sort the matrix by bitrate
B=sortrows(A,3);
ref=B(1,3);
%find the index at which the sorted matrix switches bitrate
c=1;
while B(c,3)==ref 
    c=c+1;
end
c=c-1;
%Split the matrix by indicated bitrate
C(1:c,1:3)=B(1:c,1:3)
D(1:(15-c),1:3)=B((c+1):15,1:3)
c=0;
%Check each matrix by bitrate then add it's average and
%record the increase in counter
check = double(C(1,3))
switch check
case 0.2000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,1)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,1)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    counterone=counterone+1;
    'Counter One Increased'
case  0.2500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,2)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,2)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    countertwo=countertwo+1;
    'Counter Two Increased'
case  0.3000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,3)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,3)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    counterthree=counterthree+1;
    'Counter Three Increased'
case  0.3500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,4)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,4)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    counterfour=counterfour+1;
    'Counter Four Increased'
case  0.4000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,5)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,5)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    counterfive=counterfive+1;
    'Counter Five Increased'
case  0.4500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,6)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,6)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    countersix=countersix+1;
    'Counter Six Increased'
case  0.5500
        cbrbaselayer(j-2,8)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,8)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    countereight=countereight+1;
    'Counter Eight Increased'
case  0.6000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,9)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,9)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    counternine=counternine+1;
    'Counter Nine Increased'
case  0.6500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,10)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,10)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    ounterten=counterten+1;
    'Counter Ten Increased'
case  0.7000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,11)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,11)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    countereleven=countereleven+1;
    'Counter Eleven Increased'
case  0.7500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,12)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,12)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    countertwelve=countertwelve+1;
    'Counter Twelve Increased'
case  0.8000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,13)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,13)+(mean(C(:,1))));
    counterthirteen=counterthirteen+1;
    'Counter Thirteen Increased'
end
check = double(D(1,3))
switch check
case 0.2000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,1)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,1)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    counterone=counterone+1;
    'Counter One Increased'
case  0.2500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,2)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,2)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    countertwo=countertwo+1;
    'Counter Two Increased'
case  0.3000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,3)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,3)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    counterthree=counterthree+1;
    'Counter Three Increased'
case  0.3500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,4)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,4)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    counterfour=counterfour+1;
    'Counter Four Increased'
case  0.4000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,5)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,5)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    counterfive=counterfive+1;
    'Counter Five Increased'
case  0.4500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,6)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,6)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    countersix=countersix+1;
    'Counter Six Increased'
case  0.5500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,8)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,8)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    countereight=countereight+1;
    'Counter Eight Increased'
case  0.6000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,9)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,9)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    counternine=counternine+1;
    'Counter Nine Increased'
case  0.6500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,10)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,10)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    counterten=counterten+1;
    'Counter Ten Increased'
case  0.7000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,11)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,11)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    countereleven=countereleven+1;
    'Counter Eleven Increased'
case  0.7500
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,12)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,12)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    countertwelve=countertwelve+1;
    'Counter Twelve Increased'
case  0.8000
    cbrbaselayer(j-2,13)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,13)+(mean(D(:,1))));
    counterthirteen=counterthirteen+1;
    'Counter Thirteen Increased'
end
clear A; clear B; clear C; clear D; clear check; clear c;
```

Comment: Please check the output of `check-0.3` (or whatever constant you believe to be correct). I am sure it's a floating point precision error and both values are not identical. I don't fully understand your code, but using something like `hist` probably solves the issue.

Comment: Floating point equality tests strike again :(

Comment: I have checked the output under the long format in MATLAB and found no issues. I.e. it comes out as 0.30000000, or however many I can see in the command window... is there anything in particular I can do to deal with the issue of the float point equality test. Is there some method by which I can round the answer to the nearest "tenth place" in the decimal?

Comment: What you see in the command window could be rounded. Also, it's good practice to limit your example to what is relevant (e.g. posting an example with 2 cases instead of 24).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the code is very long. Coding is to make your life easier. Not difficult.

This is my suggestion to improve the switch statement, write two sub-function, one for C and one for D

```
function checkC(inputvalue)
 index = (inputvalue-0.2)/0.05 +1;
 cbrbaselayer(j-2,index)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,index)+(mean(C(:,1))));
 eval(sprintf(counter%d = counter%d +1,index,index));
end

function checkD( inputvalue)
 index = (inputvalue-0.2)/0.05 +1;
 cbrbaselayer(j-2,index)=(cbrbaselayer(j-2,index)+(mean(D(:,1))));
 eval(sprintf(counter%d = counter%d +1,index,index));
end
```

Comment: I understand your situation. Why not just use if-else statements?

Comment: I tried that and it also did not work--same issue of equality. switch case takes up less space and looks cleaner than if else. At my quantities they are roughly equally efficient.

Comment: There was a float point issue. The solution was to round the check value to the hundredth place. 

    check = (round(100*(C(1,3)))/100)

similar function for checking D. 

Thanks for all your help!